# Bash script: one file disappears while massive renaming in loop

Tags: bash, loops, rename

I am writing a short script: User chooses a folder with photos and then these photos are sorted by date of modification and renamed with pattern "PhotoX.jpg", where X is is number from 1 to total number of photos. When I execute this script first time everything is fine. The problem is, that when I try to execute this script again, on the same files, then Photo11.jpg disappeas and I don't know why. Here is code:

```
DIRECTORY=`zenity --file-selection --title="Wybierz miejsce docelowe" --directory`
FILES=()

eval "ls -r -path $DIRECTORY/ -t > temp.txt"
COUNTER=$(wc -l < "temp.txt")
eval mapfile -t FILES < "temp.txt"

eval "cd $DIRECTORY"
COUNTER=$((COUNTER-1))
for ((i=1;i<$COUNTER;i++))
do
    eval "mv ${FILES[$i-1]} Photo$i.jpg"
done

eval "cd"
eval "rm temp.txt"
```

In all files, exept for Photo11, i get information in terminal, that `PhotoX.jpg` and `PhotoX.jpg` are the same files.

Comment: Why are you using `eval` so many times?

Comment: I am beginner in Bash, my goal is to execute terminal commands

Comment: you can't reliably populate the file-list using `eval "ls -r -path $DIRECTORY/ -t > temp.txt"`.  See why [\[ **Parsing ls** \]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is discouraged.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) describing the security impact of `eval`.

Comment: As for the immediate question -- think about what happens when you rename a file over another file you're going to process later in the loop.

Comment: ...and btw, if you want to see what's happening at runtime, `bash -x yourscript` is your friend.

Comment: You can execute a command without `eval`, just try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code given is broken enough that it's not worth debugging -- better to rewrite.

To robustly prevent the number of output files from being less than the number of input files when input and output names can overlap, it's necessary to split the renaming into two parts: From the original name to a temporary name, and from the temporary name to the output name.

```
#!/bin/bash

# prompt for a directory via zenity only if not passed in on the environment
[[ -d $directory ]] || {
  directory=$(zenity --file-selection --title="Wybierz miejsce docelowe" --directory)
}

tempnames=( )

# Move files to unique destination names, prefixed with intended final name
counter=1
while IFS= read -r -d ' ' _ && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do # read time into _
  destname="${directory}/Photo${counter}.jpg"
  [[ $filename = "$destname" ]] && continue  # skip files with correct names already
  tempname=$(mktemp -- "$destname.XXXXXX") || continue # generate a unique dest name
  mv -- "$filename" "$tempname" || {         # and rename to that...
    rm -f -- "$tempname"                     # ...deleting the tempfile and skipping the
    continue                                 #    input file if the rename somehow fails.
  }
  tempnames+=( "$tempname" )                 # ...keeping a log of what it was
  (( counter++ ))                            # finally, increment our counter.
done < <(find "$directory" -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn)

# Move from temporary names to real ones
for tempname in "${tempnames[@]}"; do
  mv "$tempname" "${tempname%.*}"
done
```

See [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) to grok how we're combining GNU `find` and GNU `sort` to get a stream of files sorted by modification time.

Comment: Even with the temp naming convention, I'd still recommend using `mv -i` just in case there's a naming conflict somewhere.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, can you describe a scenario where that conflict could happen here, without a file being created *after* the script has already started?

Comment: I don't see a way for it to overwrite files (unless, as you said, files are created while it's working); but "I don't see how this can have trouble" doesn't make me feel safe when the failure mode would involve silently and irrevocably deleting files.